# Send a email via python

Tags: python-3.x, gmail

I'm trying to send a email via smtplib, but I'm getting the following Exception:

```
     `>>> %Run 'SendEmail2 .py'
      File "/home/pi/Python Coding/SendEmail2 .py", line 17
        from smtplib import SMTPExceptionexcept smtplib.SMTPException:
           ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax`
```

**Code:**

```py
    import smtplib
    
    sender = "email1@gmail.com"
    receiver = ["email2@gmail.com"]
    message = "message_content "
    
    try:
        session = smptlib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
        session.ehlo()
        session.starttls()
        session.ehlo()
        session.login(sender,'password')
        session.sendmail(sender,receiver,message)
        session.quit()
        
    
    from smtplib import SMTPExceptionexcept smtplib.SMTPException:
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: what's that last line for?

Comment: _What_ do you mean?

Comment: **IT** still does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fistly, you have a typo in this line (`smptlib` where it should be `smtplib`):

```
session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
```

The last line doesn't make sense. Python is expecting an `except` and finds a `from...`.

```
from smtplib import SMTPExceptionexcept smtplib.SMTPException:
```

You have to catch the exception and handle it, so change your last line to something like the following.

```
except smtplib.SMTPException:
    print('Error sending email')
```

Also, note that you are calling `session.ehlo()` twice.

Finally, be sure to visit your [google account page](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps) and allow access from less secure apps.

Comment: Doesnt work. @grovina Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/Python Coding/SendEmail2 .py", line 8, in <module>
    session = smptlib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
NameError: name 'smptlib' is not defined

Comment: you have a small typo in your code... I've added the correction to my answer.

Comment: Error sending email, it says.

Comment: That's the exception being caught. remove the `try-except` so that you have a detailed error

Comment: This is all on a rasbarry pi, @grovina

Comment: `File "/home/pi/Python Coding/SendEmail2 .py", line 8
    session = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected indent`

Comment: Help..? Please...?

Comment: when you remove the try-except, be sure to reident you code! (all to the left in this case). no problem it is on raspberry.